# get props from parent component without passing to child in react

Tags: reactjs

i have

`<Row> <Col width={50} > <img src="some img" /> </Col> </Row>`

I want that Img component should get  component width.

**note**:- in this all the components are dynamically generated and lots of  and  component will be there so react context wont work out.

Comment: There is now way without prop drilling our using a state manager. check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418240/reactjs-how-a-child-access-its-parents-props

Comment: by using javascript recursive parent check we can get , but i need better solution then that .